# Is adding a scroll eventlistener bad for performance?

Tags: javascript

Is it true that adding an event listener on scroll like the bellow example is going to fire 1000s events and is bad for performance?

```
 window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
     const myDiv = document.querySelector('#my-div')
     if(myDiv) {
         myDiv.style.top = '60px';
     }
     console.log('SCROLLING');
 })
```

Comment: thousands of events if someone is scrolling a lot

Comment: It depends on what the event listener *does*. **If** you notice a performance problem, you could optimize what it does. For instance, `document.getElementById("my-div")` is *dramatically* faster than `document.querySelector("#my-div")` in absolute terms, although despite that it's still unlikely to make a difference in the vast majority of use cases.) Your event listener seems like it would be pointless after the first time it sets the div's `top`, though, so you might remove it at that point...? (Unless something else keeps setting it to something else, or removing and adding back the div.)

Comment: The code is a simplified version and yes it might be pointless after the first time. But my question is a general question.

Comment: You can use the [`passive` option to improve scrolling performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners).

Comment: often times an Intersection Observer can do what you want - of course, who knows why you want to handle scroll events in the first place

Comment: I have to use scroll event for this. But is using passive option can really help with the page performance? or it's just to improve the scrolling effect?